# selenium: how to get value when data bind to variable

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to selenium. I'm trying to get the value from the following. However even though there is a value displayed in the webpage, selenium does not show it in the outer HTML. I've also tried getting the input element and printing it's .text value and the innerHTML, and still empty. When I look at the element in the brower using debug tools and the element inspector I see a ghosted '== $0'. Even if I show outerHTML for the whole page still no value is shown but it's clearly there when I look a the page in a browser.

What's going on? How can I get the actual input value?

```
<div widget="textbox" class="l-inline-block container widget-container text-container" data-bind="{wireless5g1.ssid}" label-field="{WIRELESS_SETTINGS.WIRELESS_NETWORK_NAME}" id="widget--1ed5eee2-5134-b2f5-6ec7-a7a690939c20">
  <div class="widget-fieldlabel-wrap">
    <div class="widget-fieldlabel-inner">
      <label class="widget-fieldlabel text-fieldlabel">Network Name (SSID)</label>
      <span class="widget-separator">:</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-wrap-outer text-wrap-outer">
    <div class="widget-wrap text-wrap">
      <span class="text-wrap-before"></span>
      <span class="text-wrap-inner">
        <input type="text">
      </span>
      <span class="text-wrap-after"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Value of what element are you trying to get?

Comment: The value of this element: <input type="text">. When I look at it in browser with debug tools element browser it says <input type="text"> == $0. It is showing a valid value when presented to user in browser.